# Ajax request failed : Unexpected end of JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a beginner in JQuery and when I try to post data to my PHP page, I get the following error :

> Result : parsererror SyntaxError : unexpected end of JSON input 200 ok

Here is the code of my php page :

> ```
>      $('#contactUsForm').on('submit',function(event){
>           event.preventDefault();
>           var name  = $("#name").val();       
>           var subject = $("#subject").val();      
>           var comments = $("#commentArea").val();
>
>           var mydata = {personName:name, subjectName:name, commentArea:comments};         
>           $.ajax({            
>                     type: "POST",             
>                     url: "check_and_send_mail.php",           
>                     data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
>                     dataType: "json",             
>                     success : function(data){
>                           var erreur = typeof(reponse.Error)!='undefined' ? reponse.Error : null;
>                           var result = typeof(reponse.result)!='undefined' ? reponse.result : null;
>                           var list_grp = $("#list_grp");
>
>                           alert('it is okay');            
>                     },            
>                     error : function(xhr, status, error){
>                           alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
>                     }         
>          });   
>  });
> ```

And my check_and_send_mail.php is in the same directory than the other page and there is just that :

> ```
>       <?php       ?>
> ```

What's the solution ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
success : function(data){
                      var erreur = typeof(reponse.Error)!='undefined' ?    reponse.Error : null;
                      var result = typeof(reponse.result)!='undefined' ? reponse.result : null;
                      var list_grp = $("#list_grp");

                      alert('it is okay');            
                },
```

should look like this:

```
 success : function(reponse){
                      var erreur = typeof(reponse.Error)!='undefined' ?  reponse.Error : null;
                      var result = typeof(reponse.result)!='undefined' ? reponse.result : null;
                      var list_grp = $("#list_grp");

                      alert('it is okay');            
                },
```

You received the response in a 'data' variable and not the 'reponse' variable you are using.
Note try correcting the spelling error of 'response' to be sure it does not confuse you in the future

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to JSON stringify the data, Just update mydata variable and remove JSON.stringify

```
var mydata = {'personName':name, 'subjectName':name, 'commentArea':comments};         
$.ajax({            
    type: "POST",             
    url: "check_and_send_mail.php",           
    data: mydata,
    dataType: "json",             
    success : function(data){
       // here data is a response
    },            
    error : function(xhr, status, error){
      // handle error
    }         
});
```

then From PHP you can send the response

```
 $response = true; // Just a true response for now
 // Send the response
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
 ob_clean();
 echo json_encode($response);
 die();
```

Comment: I've tried like you advise but I've always the same error message

Comment: have you tried to update mydata variable like I have? also remove JSON.stringify. It's working perfectly fine on my end.

Comment: In your check_and_send_mail.php file don't add anything other than the code I added in my answer above to test